# Can I say "in one respect..in other respect"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, writing-style

> It is clear that there is only one legal system, which in one respect
>   should be designed rationally and discreetly, not conflicting with
>   each other, in other respect should be good in the sense that good
>   laws create good citizens, so that it is not subject to the danger of
>   being violated.(self-made)

I tried "on the one hand...on the other hand", but I soon realized that in my sentence there is no such strong sense of contrast. So I chose "in one respect", and "in other respect". Does that usage make sense to you?

Comment: Well, "in other respect" would be considered broken English.  Say "in the other respect" if there are only the two possibilities, or "in another respect" of there are more.  Perhaps try "in some respects" with "in other respects".

Comment: @GEdgar If there are only the two possibilities, I would put the definite article on both sides: _in the one respect... in the other..._

Comment: I don't see why you don't just say _... which should be designed rationally ... and should also be good in the sense ..._. Since there aren't two contrasting positions here I don't understand why you feel the need to encumber your sentence.

Comment: I appreciate highly what you teach me. To be honest, It is boring to read something like that, but this kind of speech is very frequently used in contemporaray Chinese. This is a literal translation of some words in a published Chinese article. Thank you very much, both for linguistic insight and for reminding me of the huge difference between two languages. But I donot reduce the difference to a cultuaral diversity, rather, I am willing to accept the fact that our language, our modern Chinese has many ideas and habits which are bad in general.

Comment: There is no bad and good in language, there are no values against which to measure such concepts. I think what you are looking for is a structure like "It should be _both_ A and B".

Answer (score 1):

You can, yes, but not quite as it was written in your example. I trimmed it down for the sake of clarity:

> There is only one legal system which, in one respect, should be designed rationally and, in another respect, should be good.

The two major differences are (a) "in another respect" instead of "in other respect" just as GEdgar pointed out and (b) the commas have been moved slightly. To move back to the full example:

> It is clear that there is only one legal system which, in one respect, should be designed rationally and discreetly, not conflicting with each other, and, in another respect, should be good in the sense that good laws create good citizens so that it is not subject to the danger of being violated.

The commas are hard to read because there are so many in the sentence. I would recommend rewriting the entire thing to make it flow more smoothly. But that kind of proofreading is not in scope here at EL&U.

Comment: I would say that if you split it into two sentences at that "and", it will flow more smoothly while keeping its "literal translation" quality. *"It is clear that there is only one legal system which, in one respect, should be designed rationally and discreetly, not conflicting with each other. In another respect, it should be good in the sense that good laws create good citizens so that it is not subject to the danger of being violated."*

Comment: PS. This sounds almost as if it was something said by Confucius himself.